# Set Fixed length of input text

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to set the input length of a textbox to 9 characters only. No more, no less. Is there any way to do it? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: javascript validations will help you

Comment: do you want something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/79hR3/)

Answer (score 5):

With HTML5 you can use the `pattern` attribute to do this:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".{9}" required name="patternTest" title="Field must be 9 characters long" />
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ey69U/1/)**

**[About pattern attribute](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/10-pattern.html)**

Answer (score 3):

```
var ele = document.getElementById("textboxId");
if (!(ele.value.length==9)){
  //throw validation error
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9hGv/

Comment: i am using validation descriptors, I tried a workaround by using minlen and maxlen, thanks anyway! You are much appreciated! still cant vote up tho. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set minlength and maxlenght attributes to the same value in your input.

```
<input type="text" minlength="9" maxlength="9">
```

Out of the box the browser will consider only the first 9 characters and prevent you from typing more. Using pattern you can type as many as you want but the validation will fail. Also the validation message has better user experience:

**minlength and maxlength:**

> Please lengthen this text to 9 characters or more (you are currently
>   using 8 characters).

**pattern:**

> Please match the requested format.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an input you can use attribute `maxlength=9`, of course in this case you can have less than 9, but it would be good to validate it and not send the form in less than 9 and display an error.

If it's a textarea element, you would need javascript to do that

Answer (score 0):

this is example -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
  <title>index</title>

  </head>
  <body>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   function chkpassword() {

    var p1 = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var min = 9
    if(p1.length == min) {
        alert('ok')
    } else{
       alert(":( The password must be at least 9 characters long.");
    }

     }

  </script>

      <input type=text id=pass name=pass value="" style='width:245px'  >  
      <input type=button id=btnOk name=btnOk value="OK" onclick='chkpassword()' />
       </body>
      </html>
```

use this code to get your solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question?